# Why the application stopped working when clicked on any item?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, clicklistener

I am working on recyclerview. Recently I added an item click listener, but when I clicked on the item the application stopped working.

Here is the adapter class:

```
public class RVAdapter extends
RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {

 ArrayList<String>itemlist;
 Clicklistener clicklistener=null;

 public void setClicklistener(Clicklistener clicklistener) {
     this.clicklistener = clicklistener;
 }

 public RVAdapter(ArrayList<String> itemlist) {
     this.itemlist = itemlist;
 }

 public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

     private TextView text;

     public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
         super(itemView);
         itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
         text= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemtextView);
     }

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         if(clicklistener!=null)
             clicklistener.itemClicked(v,getAdapterPosition());

     }
 }

 @Override
 public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);
     ItemViewHolder iv=new ItemViewHolder(v);

     return iv;
 }

 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
     holder.text.setText(itemlist.get(position));
 }


 @Override
 public int getItemCount() {
     return itemlist.size();
 }

}
```

Here is the main class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Clicklistener {

    ArrayList<String> list;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RVAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        list=new ArrayList<>();

        list.add("ABC");
        list.add("DEF");
        list.add("GHI");
        list.add("JKL");
        recyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RV);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter=new RVAdapter(list);
        adapter.setClicklistener(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);




        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void itemClicked(View view, int position) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And the interface

```
public interface Clicklistener {
    void itemClicked(View view, int position);
}
```

Comment: Show your LogCat Response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass `int` position to `Toast.makeText()` and it thinks that it is a resource id value, and stops with message which looks like that: 'could not find string with id ...'

Simply replace it with `String.valueOf(position)`.